# does GetType() guarantee casting?

Tags: c#

if `o.GetType() == sometype` is it guaranteed that `o` can be casted to `sometype` ?

that is if:

```
void f<T>(T o1, object o2) {
   if (o1.GetType() != o2.GetType()) return;
   T t = o2 as T;
   // can I assert that t is not null ??
}
```

Comment: This looks like an XY problem, or at least there's a code smell here...

Comment: Yes, it's guaranteed, but that code doesn't make a lot of sense as-is

Comment: To be specific, your code violates this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: Sounds to me like you actually want to use interfaces. Generics are not that.

Comment: it's part of a bigger thing, if you look at my extension method here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54934113/460084 I was wondering if the `&& obj is T o && thisEquals(o)` can be safely shortcutted to `&& thisEquals(o as T)` ?

Comment: Obviously not going to work for value types. Regular cast would be fine

Comment: There is no guarantee that `T` and `o1.GetType()` will be the same type (`T` could be `object` for example, while `GetType()` would return the **real** type). I am not saying that is a problem, just pointing it out in case it impacts your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but I'd suggest going one step further and do this:

```
void f<T, U>(T t, U u) where T : class
{
    if (!t.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(u.GetType())) return;
    T ut = u as T;
    // can I assert that t is not null ?? Yes, you can
}
```

`IsAssignableFrom` should nail it for any type.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the `is` operator, <sup>1</sup>Albeit "maybe" a little slower

```
if (o2 is SomeType result) o1 = result;
```

or as a method

```
private void SomeThingWeird<T>(ref T o1, object o2)
{
   if (o2 is T result)
      o1 = result;
}
```

---

**References**

<sup>1</sup> [Drilling into .NET Runtime microbenchmarks: ‘typeof’ optimizations](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vancem/2006/10/01/drilling-into-net-runtime-microbenchmarks-typeof-optimizations/).

Comment: @Enigmativity maybe wrongly assumed this was a swappsies method and OP wanted the result to reflect back to the caller

Comment: Reading the comments, i see what the extended method does, so them there was a fly (again)

Answer (score -1):

Why not doing :

```
void f<T>(T o1, T o2) {
   if (o1.GetType() != o2.GetType()) return;
   // can I assert that t is not null ??
}
```

For what I understand you want, by checking `if (o1.GetType() != o2.GetType()) return;` to make sure that `o2` is of type `T` and not a derived type. So `o2` has to be of type `T` and you don't have any problem casting.